# Series within dataframe are different lengths, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas

I know this might be difficult to visualize without an example, but reproducing one for you folks would be a nightmare haha.

**I am getting the below error:**

> ```
> ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. 
> The length of column argument df['color'] is 11109, whereas 
> the length of  previously-processed arguments  
> ['$_Amount','Company_Name', 
> 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Funding_Program_Name'] is 11111
> ```

Basically I am trying to plot on a scatter map some data, but one column is 2 rows shorter than the rest after plowing through the raw data. (Unsure how this happened)

I have tried `.replace(np.nan,0)`
I have tried `.dropna()`
Also tried `.replace('',0)`

I guess I cannot operate on something that doesn't "exist" and so the above have not fixed the problem

But I think the solution would involve somehow adding cell data to the empty to slots in the ['color'] column, and I am unsure how to do this. Any tips?!

Comment: Basically you have to remove two values from the larger series or add two values to the shorter series. But if you don't know how the two values went missing, you don't know where to fill/remove, right?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch that's right, not sure where they are missing (and a more general solution would be best for a future dataset). However, I am sure about the column in which they are missing. Wondering if there is a some kind of a .fill () function

Comment: removing the 2 additional rows, or adding to the missing 2 cells in df['color'] are both fine by me! Whatever works best

Comment: You can use `series1.append(series2)` to generate a new series. Just create a series `series2` with two fill values and append that to the shorter series. Or you can use `series1.iloc[:-2]` to get `series1` without the last two entries. But I'm really concerned with that: Your data has companies and amounts of money associated with each other. If you don't know where data went missing, how do you know that the entries are still in the correct rows?